# Specify files with *

Tags: git, bash, git-commit

I am running Git Bash and GUI under Windows XP thus in a mingw environment.

I created two files, a and b, with vi, added them and then committed them. Then I modified both again, then using git bash added a but not b. Git GUI verified that a was staged but not b.

Next I typed the following:

`git commit -m "Staged a, not b, committing with * file specifier" *`

Git GUI indicates that both were committed.

I repeated the experiment but used GUI to attempt the commit. It only committed file a.

Is the * file specifier a problem?

Comment: are you looking for `git add --all`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how the GUI works but did you type in the exact same command into the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: Yes, because you told git to commit the files you specified instead of letting it commit the already staged changes.

From the git-commit [`man page`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html):

> <file>…
>
> When files are given on the command line, the command commits the contents of the named files, without recording the changes already
>   staged. The contents of these files are also staged for the next
>   commit on top of what have been staged before.

Comment: Also, the only reason git allowed his changes is because it already knew about the files. If he did not add them previously, `git commit *` would not commit them.

Comment: @TravisJacobs Indeed, at least here that causes git to spit out an error message.